# python pandas dataframe words in context: get 3 words before and after

Tags: python, pandas, text, cpu-word

I am working in jupyter notebook and have a pandas dataframe "data":

```
Question_ID | Customer_ID | Answer
      1           234         Data is very important to use because ... 
      2           234         We value data since we need it ...
```

I want to go through the text in column "Answer" and get the three words before and after the word "data".
So in this scenario I would have gotten "is very important"; "We value", "since we need".

Is there an good way to do this within a pandas dataframe? So far I only found solutions where "Answer" would be its own file run through python code (without a pandas dataframe). While I realize that I need to use the NLTK library, I haven't used it before, so I don't know what the best approach would be. (This was a great example [Extracting a word and its prior 10 word context to a dataframe in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936345/extracting-a-word-and-its-prior-10-word-context-to-a-dataframe-in-python))

Comment: can you show the initial raw dataframe structure(not its output)?

Comment: it's just a csv I read in as a data frame with data = pd.read_csv('U:\data science\data.csv')

Comment: since you only want three words before and after "data", shouldn't your example be "since we need", which doesn't include "it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

for value in df.Answer.values:
    non_data = re.split('Data|data', value) # split text removing "data"
    terms_list = [term for term in non_data if len(term) > 0] # skip empty terms
    substrs = [term.split()[0:3] for term in terms_list]  # slice and grab first three terms
    result = [' '.join(term) for term in substrs] # combine the terms back into substrings
    print result
```

output:

```
['is very important']
['We value', 'since we need']
```

Comment: thank you, this worked and gave me some examples, but it also gave me the same error "TypeError: expected string or buffer"; is there a way to specify the column astype str?

Comment: which line number gives you that TypeError?

Comment: thank you very much for your help; I greatly appreciate it; how can I attach a snippet of the csv in stackoverflow? I have been googling it, but it seems not supported; this is the full error I get

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-3c6d090fcbc0> in <module>()
      1 for value in df.Answer.values:
----> 2     non_data = re.split('customers|customer', value)
      3     terms_list = [term for term in non_data if len(term) > 0] # skip empty terms
      4     substrs = [term.split()[0:3] for term in terms_list]  # slice and grab first three terms
      5     result = [' '.join(term) for term in substrs] # combine the terms back into substrings

Comment: C:\Users\jdagher\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\re.pyc in split(pattern, string, maxsplit, flags)
    169     """Split the source string by the occurrences of the pattern,
    170     returning a list containing the resulting substrings."""
--> 171     return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
    172 
    173 def findall(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: so the rows affected by the error are ----> 2     non_data = re.split('customers|customer', value) and --> 171     return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)

Comment: Yes you're right, it looks like the Answer column is not being read as a string.  To read the data file as a string, try `pd.read_csv('U:\data science\data.csv', dtype=object)`

Comment: thank you, I did that and I did dropna(); but I am still getting the same error

Comment: how did you create your `data.csv` file? it must have some metadata or formatting in it that we're not aware of

Comment: I used this and it finally worked answers_str = df.Answer.apply(str)

Answer (score 0):

The solution using *generator expression*, `re.findall` and `itertools.chain.from_iterable` functions:

```
import pandas as pd, re, itertools

data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')  # change with your current file path

data_adjacents = ((i for sublist in (list(filter(None,t))
                         for t in re.findall(r'(\w*?\s*\w*?\s*\w*?\s+)(?=\bdata\b)|(?<=\bdata\b)(\s+\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*)', l, re.I)) for i in sublist)
                            for l in data.Answer.tolist())

print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data_adjacents)))
```

The output:

```
[' is very important', 'We value ', ' since we need']
```

Comment: I get this error TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: looks like you have passed an incorrect argument, check the line which causes the error and specify the expected type